# How to hook up a HC-06 to Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-nano, resistor, hc-06

So I have an arduino nano hooked up to hc-06 however every diagram of the hookup wires shows some kind of resistors (1K and 2K, rather high resistances to ignore), and I completely overlooked them. I hooked it up to my computer and it all lit up nice, however I am wondering why those resistors would be included if it still lights up. Am I slowly damaging my equipment over time?

Answer (score 1):

The HC-06 itself is a 3.3V device, while the Arduino Uno/Nano is a 5V device. When using electronic devices you need to stay within their corresponding voltage limits, both in power and IO connections.

Most HC-06 boards, that you can buy, will also include a voltage regulator for the power, regulating the 5V from the Arduino down to 3.3V. If you have one of these, you can provide 5V to the HC-06 as power (otherwise you would need to use the 3V pin of the Arduino as power source for the HC-06). But these boards mostly don't have a level translation for the IO lines. And that's where the resistors come in.

The HC-06 has 2 IO lines: RX and TX.

- TX will send data to the Arduino and thus be driven by the HC-06 with its 3.3V. The Arduino runs on 5V, but will still be reading 3.3V as a digital HIGH level. Thus this line is not a problem.
- The RX line will be driven by the Arduino at 5V. Most devices don't like a voltage on their IO pins, that is significantly higher than their working voltage (for power). Thus you can damage the HC-06 receiving hardware, if you directly connect Arduino and HC-06.

To solve that problem you have 2 options for level translation between 3.3V and 5V:

- The proper way would be to use a transistor based level translator you can get these as ready-to-use board for rather cheap (search on the big online platforms for "level translator" or "level converter"), or you can build them yourself using transistors and resistors.
- Or you can use a voltage divider consisting of two resistors. When you connect them like ground -> 2kOhm resistor -> 1kOhm resistor -> TX of the Arduino, you will get the Arduinos TX signal divided down to 3.3V at the point between the two resistors. There you can connect the HC-06 RX pin. This method has drawbacks, since it also acts as parasitic low pass filter. That limits the transmission speed (baud rate). Though you can still easily drive baudrates as high as 115200 baud, which is sufficient in most cases.

So it is not a good option to just omit the resistors. It can lead to damaging the HC-06. You can choose between the above options.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! You have a good question but a little light on details. You may have damaged something, there is not enough detail to tell. You state hc-06 but no link to the module you used. They come in 3.3 and 5V models. The resistors are used to translate the voltage down, this you should never do, you are playing with tolerances and if wrong you could destroy the part. If you have a 5V Arduino and a 3.3V HC-06 Get a translator or a 5V HC-06. Lighting up only tells you there is power there. The lights (LEDs) are operational even if the micro is not even on the board. Are you slowly damaging your equipment over time? Possibly I cannot tell with what you have told us. You have not even stated it worked or not and if you even powered up.

Comment: After closer inspection it did say 3.3v I should've paid more attention. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: @PeterDragomirov If you think one of the answers is correct, you can mark it as such. That way everyone knows, that that is the correct one and that the question was successfully answered